# R Keras - Why can't I load model?

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I am building the following network in R to solve a regression problem (stock price prediction):

```r
library(keras)
library(tfdatasets)

features_spec <- feature_spec(dataset = df, 
                              x = all_of(features), 
                              y = all_of(target_col)) %>%
  step_numeric_column(all_numeric(), normalizer_fn = scaler_standard()) %>%
  fit()

input_layer <- layer_input_from_dataset(df_features)
  
output_layer <- input_layer %>%
    layer_dense_features(dense_features(features_spec)) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 10,
                activation = "softplus") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1)
  
model <- keras_model(input_layer, output_layer)
  
model %>% compile(
      loss = "mae",
      optimizer = "adam"
    )

model %>% fit(
      x = df_features,
      y = df_target_col,
      epochs = 6,
      validation_split = 0.2
    )
```

And then I am saving it and then loading it back again with the following code:

```r
model %>% save_model_hdf5("nn.hdf5")

loaded_model <- load_model_hdf5("nn.hdf5")
```

But when loading it, I get the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have tried using `compile=FALSE` when loading, or saving and loading using `save_model_tf()` and `load_model_tf()`, but i still get the same error. What is happening?

Comment: Just to make sure, you might want to retry saving with named arguments: `... %>% save_model_hdf5(object = ., filepath = "nn.hdf5")`

Comment: I tried that, still same issue